# Making specific moves in a turn based fighting game

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a turn based fighting game in Java Eclipse. Right now there's nothing wrong with my code but I just needed help figuring out a way to add multiple attacks to each of my characters in the game.

This is my main method

```
public class Main {
      
    public static Random generator = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String answer = "yes";
        while(answer.equals("yes")) {
        Character player1 = new Wraith();
        Character player2 = new Paladin();
        
        
        Scanner charInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Player1, Choose your character");
        String choice = charInput.nextLine();
        
        if(choice.equals("Paladin")) {
            player1 = new Paladin();
        }
        if(choice.equals("Wizard")) {
            player1 = new Wizard();
        }
        if(choice.equals("Wraith")) {
            player1 = new Wraith();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Player2, Choose your character");
        String choice2 = charInput.nextLine();
        
        if(choice2.equals("Paladin")) {
            player2 = new Paladin();
        }
        if(choice2.equals("Wizard")) {
            player2 = new Wizard();
        }
        if(choice2.equals("Wraith")) {
            player2 = new Wraith();
        }
        //player1.name = input("Player1 pick your character(Paladin, Wraith, Wizard)", charInput);

        //player2.name = input("Player2 pick your character(Paladin, Wraith, Wizard)", charInput);

        System.out.println(player1.name + " vs. " + player2.name);
        System.out.println(player1.health + " vs. " + player2.health);

        
       
        
        while (player1.isAlive() && player2.isAlive()) {

            System.out.println(player1.name + ": " + player1.health);
            System.out.println(player2.name + ": " + player2.health);

            int damage;

            damage = player1.attack(player2);
            System.out.println(player1.name + " hits " + player2.name + " for " + damage);

            damage = player2.attack(player1);
            System.out.println(player2.name + " hits " + player1.name + " for " + damage);
        }

        if(player1.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println(player1.name + " wins!");
        } else if (player2.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println(player2.name + " wins!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's a draw!");
        }
        }
        }
    private static String input(String string, Scanner charInput) {
        
        return null;
    }


}
```

This is one of my character classes

````
public class Wizard extends Character {

 public int dexterity = 25;
    public static Random generator = new Random();
    public Wizard(){
        super();
        this.name = "Wizard";
        this.strength = 10;
        this.defense = 8;
        this.health = 95;
    }

    public int attack(Character target){
        boolean criticalHit =Main.generator.nextInt(150) < dexterity;
        int damage = this.strength * 2;
        if(criticalHit){
            damage *= 2;
            System.out.println("*** Critical Hit ***");
        }
        int damageDealt = target.takeDamage(damage);
        return damageDealt;        
    }
    


}```

And this is my main character class
````

public class Character {

```
public String name;
public int strength;
public int health;
public int defense;

public int takeDamage(int damage){
    int damageTaken = damage - this.defense;
    this.health -= damageTaken;
    return damageTaken;
}

public int attack(Character target){
    int damage = this.strength * 2;
    int damageDealt = target.takeDamage(damage);
    return damageDealt;
}

public boolean isAlive(){
    return health > 0;
}
```

}```
also I'm new to coding and stack overflow so and suggestions on how to make my posts make more sense or something like that is much appreciated

Comment: for further question about game mechanics you should visit https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice implemention of a battle system.

when a `Character` performs an `attack` you choose which attack that should be and execute:

```
public int attack(Character target){
    AttackMode mode = determineAttackMode(target); // the charater chooses what kind of attack he will execute during this attack
    switch(mode){
        case AttackMode.DOUBLESTRIKE: return attackDoubleStrike(target);
        case AttackMode.BURST: return attackBurst(target);
        default: return attackDefault(target); // your previously implemented method attack(target)
    }
}
```

The AttackMode is an Enum class:

```
    enum AttackMode {DEFAULT, DOUBLESTRIKE, BURST}
```

i'm not sure how double damage is dealt, so this is a guess here

```
public int attackDoubleStrike(Character target){
    int firstStrike = attackDefault(target);     
    int secondStrike = attackDefault(target);  
    return firstStrike + secondStrike;
}
```